# I cant Render My longitude and latitude in Powerbi service neither the desktop

Tags: azure, powerbi

This a strange issue earlier I was able to render my table that contains the longitude and latitude visuals and can see them inside the bing maps, but after the latest update of PowerBI(December 2017), I cant see the latitude and longitude with the Bing maps on the latest update. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the data type of your field is *Decimal Number*:

1. Select the column/field in the field pane
2. Click the *Modeling* tab
3. In the *Formatting* section, for *Data type* select *Decimal Number*

[image]

Do this for both columns, *Latitude* and *Longitude*.

Comment: That was right, But why we cant select latitude and longitude field when they are present in the power query?? Why we are selecting here the decimal.

Comment: It is simply an extra validation.